# Managing multiple elements from an API response

Tags: android, kotlin

kotlin junior here.

I have this current piece of code in my App:

```
disposable.add(
                client
                        .doLoginRx(req)
                        .toObservable()
                        .map { response -> response.accessToken }
                        .doOnNext { token -> logIn(token, email) }
                        .flatMap { token -> client.loadUserSettingsRx(token).toObservable() }
                        .applySchedulers()
                        .subscribe({ onLoginSuccess(it) }, { onLoginFail(it) }))
```

**doLoginRx()** performs an api call that returns multiple values in json format. Currently the code maps one of those values (**accessToken**) and then passes it to the method below, **logIn()**.

My task is to change this **logIn()** method and pass it some other values provided in the response.

How do I write that?

PD: this is the model of the response

```
data class LoginResponseV2(
    @JsonProperty("access_token")
    val accessToken: String?,
    @JsonProperty("token_type")
    val tokenType: String?,
    @JsonProperty("expires_in")
    val expiresIn: Int?,
    @JsonProperty("refresh_token")
    val refreshToken: String?,
    @JsonProperty("created_at")
    val createdAt: String?
): BaseResponse()
```

My goal would be to provide **logIn()** with the other 4 values (tokenType, expiresIn, refreshToken, createdAt)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: not sure what's the return type of `.toObservable()` and `.doOnNext{}` but did you try removing the `.map{}` so that you will get the respose inside  `.doOnNext{}`

Comment: So I tried removing the .map line and provide all the params to ```logIn()```like this: .doOnNext { response -> logIn(response.accessToken, response.tokenType, response.expiresIn, response.refreshToken, response.createdAt, email) }
Every value is null, so I guess a map function is still needed.
PD: .map { response -> response} does not help either